# How to italicize text in NSAlert?

Tags: cocoa

How can I add italicize certain parts of text in an NSAlert?

```
 NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:NSLocalizedString(@"Warning", nil)
                                  defaultButton:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                alternateButton:nil
                                    otherButton:nil
                      informativeTextWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"I want to italicize the word awesome in this text", nil)];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put whatever you want in the accessory view, which is located between the informative text or suppression checkbox (if present) and the response buttons. The example in the [documentation for NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under `setAccessoryView:` shows how to do this. Unfortunately all the other text methods in the `NSAlert` only take `NSString` and not `NSAttributedString`. This discussion of using [NSAttributedString in NSAlert](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/155037-nsattributedstring-alert-panels.html) suggests that the obvious hacks don't work. You are better off just making your own alert window class.